# javascript onchange query issue

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following javascript at the head of my file.

```
<?php
echo "<script language='JavaScript'>\n";
echo "var times = new Array();\n";
echo "times[0] = 0;\n";
foreach($times as $time)
{
echo "times[". $time->DESC ."] = " . $time->FEE . ";\n";
}
echo "</script>\n";
?>
```

i then have a dropdown, where the options are the same $time->DESC,

i have an onchange, and i want to set another text box value to equal the PBT_FEE according to the PBT_DESC

i have

```
onchange="document.getElementById('Price').value = times[this.value];"
```

i presume that times[this.value] should call for the fee according to the matching descriptions, but i get no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this playing with the w3schools example, and it works, so I'm guessing your problem is somewhere in the html elements.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var times = new Array();
times[0] = 0;
times[1] = 1;
times[2] = 4;
times[3] = 7;
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select onchange="document.getElementById('finalPrice').value = times[this.value];">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="fname" id="finalPrice" /><br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok well my array indexes are strings, could that be the issue?

Comment: That should work too. As long as your array indexes match the option value fields. Each `<option value="index">` should have a `times["index"] = something`.

Comment: got it to work, i had to add quotes into the php concatenation

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be getting the value of the dropdown box, instead of the times[this.value]...